# Xubuntu panel disappears every time I restart

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, panel

Well, I recently installed Xubuntu 14.04 and every time I restart, the top panel disappears.

As a solution I found the following commands to make the panel reappears, but I have to run it in terminal every time I reboot:

```
xfce4-panel --quit
pkill xfconfd
rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/panel
rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml
xfce4-panel
```

Is there any way to make this happen every time I reboot?
The other options here didn't work to me.

If I run after restart only `xfce4-panel` it says:

```
xfce4-panel: there is already and instance running
```

Comment: Did you try this http://askubuntu.com/a/359590/265974 ?

Comment: Ty but didn't work sorry

Comment: Did the panel appears after reboot if you run `xfce4-panel -r` ?

Comment: No, only if I run the first comands

Comment: Can you [clear your session cache](http://askubuntu.com/a/475284/265974) after you run the commands to recreate the panel on reboot. Than try to reboot again.

Comment: Ty , works now!!

Comment: @TuKsn: could you convert your upvoted comment to an answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in this area, but you could try creating a script to run those commands in that order and setting it up to run a startup. You could also try going into your panel settings and unchecking the box labeled "Automatically show and hide the panel".

Comment: Please explain, how to do that (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)).

Comment: How to create a script? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Run your working commands:

```
xfce4-panel --quit
pkill xfconfd
rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/panel
rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml
xfce4-panel
```

then [Clear your session cache](https://askubuntu.com/a/475284/265974)